# How can I have Desmos trace a point's path?

Tags: desmos, graph

I have [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sltczbaedj) graph on Desmos. How can I have it trace the red point as *t<sub>v</sub>* increases, and un-trace it as it decreases back to 0?

Thanks,
Cat

Comment: Also, is this the right SE site? This was the best one I could think of.

Comment: [math.se] does have a [tag called desmos](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desmos). But I am not familiar enough with Desmos-related questions on that site to be able to say whether or not this would be considered on-topic on that site.